# How to use WriteConsoleInput() in MFC?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, mfc

I can use WriteConsoleInput() in console application. But when I try to use  writeConsoleInput() in MFC it not type any thing in command window. This's my code.

```
DWORD WINAPI test(LPVOID lp)
{
    system("edit");
    return 0;
}

void CVirusScanDlg::OnBnClickedFormat()
{
    HANDLE hConIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE hConOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD dwTmp;
    INPUT_RECORD ir[5];

    CreateThread(NULL, 0, test,(LPDWORD)0, 0, &dwTmp);

    Sleep( 1000 );

    ir[0].EventType = KEY_EVENT;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown = TRUE;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = 0;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar = 'u';
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = 'U';
    ir[0].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = MapVirtualKey('U', MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

    ir[1].EventType = KEY_EVENT;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown = TRUE;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = 0;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar = 'c';
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = 'C';
    ir[1].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = MapVirtualKey('C', MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

    ir[2].EventType = KEY_EVENT;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown = TRUE;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = 0;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar = 'i';
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = 'I';
    ir[2].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = MapVirtualKey('I', MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

    ir[3].EventType = KEY_EVENT;
    ir[3].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown = TRUE;
    ir[3].Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = 0;
    ir[3].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar = VK_RETURN;
    ir[3].Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
    ir[3].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = VK_RETURN;
    ir[3].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = MapVirtualKey(VK_RETURN, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

    ir[4].EventType = KEY_EVENT;
    ir[4].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown = FALSE;
    ir[4].Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = 0;
    ir[4].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar = VK_RETURN;
    ir[4].Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
    ir[4].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = VK_RETURN;
    ir[4].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = MapVirtualKey(VK_RETURN, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

    dwTmp = 0;
    WriteConsoleInput(hConIn, ir, 5, &dwTmp);
    //FlushConsoleInputBuffer(hConIn);
    //WriteConsole(hConIn, "uci\n", 5, &dwTmp, NULL);
    //printf(" dwTmp = %d ", dwTmp);

    Sleep(1000);

  //return 0;
}
```

when I run this code it not type anything in command window. How to use WriteConsoleInput() in MFC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't MFC per se.  The problem is that a GUI app doesn't *have* console I/O ... unless you explicitly do a ConsoleAlloc() etc.

Here are some good links:

- http://dslweb.nwnexus.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm
- http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2009/03/01/how-to-attach-a-console-to-your-gui-app-in-c/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682528.aspx